# Handling unknown structs imported from dll

Tags: c++, dll, struct

I have tried to streamline this, but if you need more detail or code, let me know.

First, some background: I am making a module for a C++ program using exported functions from a .dll to communicate with it. I do not have support from the original developer, so I do not have access to the source code, headers, .lib, or anything else. I used dependency walker to get a list of function names, and explicitly linked using getProcAddress with success on most functions. ([Here is the solution I used to get this far.](http://recxltd.blogspot.com/2012/02/working-with-c-dll-exports-without.html))

Now the problem I have run into is how to handle unknown structs. For example, I have access to the following equations:

```
foo::bar::bar(void)
struct foo::bar magic(void)
foo::baz::baz(struct foo::bar const &)
int foo::baz::qux(void)
```

So the top function is a constructor that makes an object with the same name as the struct. The second function is a magic function that outputs the struct with all the data in it. The third function is another constructor that makes a new object with that struct as an input. The final function outputs an integer value (what I really care about) with the object just created.

As you can see, I don't know, nor do I care what is in the struct. It just gets magically created and immediately passed to another function that deals with it. So here is how I attempted to handle it (look at the solution linked in the first paragraph if this doesn't make sense):

```
struct barStruct {
    void** unknown1[1024];
    void** unknown2[1024];
    void** unknown3[1024];
};

typedef barStruct (*_magic) (char *);
typedef void (*_bazConstructor) (char *, struct barStruct const &);
typedef int (*_qux) (char *);
```

I think I figured out how many elements there are in barStruct because bazConstructor will crash if there are too many. The problem is, no matter what I have tried, qux will crash. I am guessing this has something to do with how I am handling barStruct. Is it necessary to define the struct like this? Is there a way to pass it directly from magic to the bazconstructor without trying to say what is in it?

Basically: How should I handle a struct if I have no idea what it is supposed to contain?

Comment: If the DLL exports are really C++ then the struct they are expecting may require a constructor/deconstructor/vtable/etc as may any member classes it might contain. In short, you may not just be able to pass it a gob of memory and expect it to work.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Would I be right in guessing that foo::bar::bar(void) is the struct constructor? or is having the same name a coincidence. Does this mean I need to pass the struct object pointer to foo::baz::baz(struct foo::bar const &) somehow?

Comment: You need an assembly-level debugger, every reverse-engineering tool you can lay your hands on, tons of elbow grease, and luck.

Comment: If you have absolutely no way to get at least the headers for this external DLL you're working with, then you will have to resort to reverse-engineering the DLL or re-implement the DLL's functionality yourself. Either way, it will not be easy.